# arra_multisort using parameters at the same time

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following PHP array and I would like to sort it first by year and then by type:

```
$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
        'type' => array('conference', 'journal', 'conference', 'conference','conference'),
    );
```

Until now I did: ([codepad](http://codepad.org/Iexn2us2)) It is sorting by type but not by year.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string|int $by key/offset
 * @param array $order
 * @return array
 */
function array_multisort_by_order(array $array, $by, array $order)
{
     $max = max(array_map('count',$array));
    //or, alternatively, depending on input (if there are no 'complete' subarrays):
    //$max = max(array_map(function($arr){return max(array_keys($arr));},$array))+1;
    foreach($array as &$sub){
        $addin = array_diff_key(array_fill(0,$max,null),$sub);
        $sub = $addin + $sub;
        ksort($sub);
    }
    $order = array_flip($order);
    $params[] = $array[$by];
    foreach($params[0] as &$v) $v = $order[$v];
    foreach($array as &$v) $params[] = &$v; unset($v);
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $params);
    //no closeures here:
     //foreach($array as &$sub) $sub = array_filter(function($a){return   !is_null($a);},$sub);
    $filter = create_function('$a','return !is_null($a);');
    foreach($array as &$sub) $sub = array_filter($sub,$filter);
    return $array;
}
$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
        'type' => array('conference', 'journal', 'conference', 'conference','conference'),
    );

print_r($array);

// Usage:
$array = array_multisort_by_order($array, 'type', array('conference', 'journal'));

print_r($array);
?>
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
[note] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test2
        [2] => test3
        [3] => test4
        [4] => test1
    )

[year] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2011
        [1] => 2012
        [2] => 2009
        [3] => 2010
        [4] => 2010
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => conference
        [1] => conference
        [2] => conference
        [3] => conference
        [4] => journal
    )

)
```

Desired output: (Sorted by type and by year.)

```
Array
(
[note] => Array
    (
        [0] => test2
        [1] => test
        [2] => test4
        [3] => test3
        [4] => test1
    )

[year] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2012
        [1] => 2011
        [2] => 2010
        [3] => 2009
        [4] => 2010
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => conference
        [1] => conference
        [2] => conference
        [3] => conference
        [4] => journal
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for sorting the way you have mentioned.

```
<?

$array = array(
        'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
        'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
        'type' => array('conference', 'journal', 'conference', 'conference','conference'),
);


// Storing the original keys
$original_keys = array_keys($array);

$temp_array = array();

// Restructuring the array for sorting
foreach($array as $items){
   $index = 0;
        foreach($items as $item){
            $temp_array[$index++][] = $item;
       }
}


array_multisort($array['type'], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $array['year'], SORT_DESC, $temp_array);

// Restoring the temp array in original format
$array = array();
foreach($temp_array as $items){
    $index = 0;
    foreach($original_keys as $key){
       $array[$key][] = $items[$index++];
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Working demo at: 
http://codepad.org/GMpf7pFt

Comment: Thanks for yout time. The problem is that I also want the `$array['type']` according the values of another array. For example in the array I was sorting through `$array = array_multisort_by_order($array, 'type', array('conference', 'journal'));`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. I just looked at input and expected output and came up with a code above.